# Dynamic room creation using xirsys STUN and TURN

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, easyrtc

Xirsys STUN and TURN server requires registering of rooms within application else using default room name (created while defining app name). However, my requirement is to create a new room for each video/audio request, which in turn will be a dynamic room creation. Since, the new dynamically created room has not been registered with the XIRSys application, my STUN and TURN configuration fails. Please suggest how to move forward.

Additionally, I am using easyrtc setup along with XirSys STUN and TURN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Xirsys api, documentation at: http://xirsys.com/api/